# linearly independent vector union is linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

true or false
linearly independent vector union is linearly independent?

I need to know if this fact is true to be able to use it in a proof

Comment: What do you mean about a "union" in this case...  If as I am interpreting your question to be is "If $A=\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m\}$ is a linearly independent set of vectors and $B=\{b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n\}$ is another linearly independent set of vectors, is $A\cup B$ also a linearly independent set of vectors?"  then the answer is an obvious no.  Just take $A=B$ as a counterexample.

Comment: @JMoravitz Your counterexample works if the independent sets are indexed families or if they're multisets, but not if they're just sets, because with $A=B$ you'll have $A\cup B=A=B$. But there are plenty of easy examples that work with plain sets.

Comment: @AndreasBlass fair enough.  Then take as a different counter example $\Bbb R^2$ with $A=\{[1,0],[0,1]\}$ and $B=\{[1,1],[1,-1]\}$.  The end result is that this claim should have been obviously suspicious.